# word for a correction or change made retroactively

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a noun that means a correction/amendment/addition made to a text after the text has been "finalised"

> JK Rowling's many ______s posted on twitter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A term that is specific to literary (and not academic) works is a **retcon**, which is short for [retroactive continuity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_continuity).

> a literary device in which established diegetic facts in the plot of a fictional work (those established through the narrative itself) are adjusted, ignored, or contradicted by a subsequently published work

I would feel that small changes, which do not affect the understanding of the literary work, could be described as *errata*, but something that changes the reader's interpretation of the work is a *retcon*.

Answer (score 5):

A possible word for this is ***errata*** (singular ***erratum***), which is a list of errors and their corrections in some text after it has been published. Errata are often seen in academic journals in order to fix relatively small errors - you wouldn't generally see major changes that drastically alter a manuscript's interpretation appear as errata, for example. Minor details in a novel that need to be fixed, like the color of someone's eyes or what hand someone was holding something  in, would be the types of things to appear in errata.

Another term for errata is ***corrigenda***, but I've never encountered that word "in the wild".

Comment: I've sometimes seen corrigenda used for corrections made at the level of an individual paper (whereas errata are usually a collection for an entire journal edition). It's certainly less common

Answer (score 2):

Regarding @NuclearHoggie's I was going to comment, but something more extensive seems needed.

Erratum is a good choice, however it is restricted to errors, not additions. Corrigenda, which I have never heard of but the dictionary has, also seems to be restricted to errors. Thanks though Hoggie, I learned a new word from you!

Frankly I don't see anything wrong with correction/amendment/addition. Perhaps he is looking for one word that covers them all. In that case erratum and corrigenda will not work because and addition is neither.

However, I wonder why we need such esoteric words when "change" seems perfectly adequate.

> JK Rowling's many changes posted on twitter

Answer (score 1):

How about 'revision'? I'd take that to be a change or a correction to something previously stated.

Answer (score 0):

"Alteration**s**"

the action or process of altering or being altered
(https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define+alterations).

late 14c., alteracioun, "change, transformation, action of altering," from Old French alteracion "change, alteration" (14c.), and directly from Medieval Latin alterationem (nominative alteratio), noun of action from past-participle stem of Late Latin alterare "to change," from Latin alter "the other (of the two)," from ... https://www.etymonline.com/word/alteration